# How to disable small tile support on metro style?

Tags: c#, windows-8, tile, microsoft-metro

I've heard in a video (which I have since lost the link to...it may have been on Channel9), that we can disable small tile support in Windows 8 metro. How i can do this in C#?

Comment: What video? Where did you hear this? Did they provide any information on how to do it in a different language?

Comment: let me jump to the top and ask again, where did you hear this? what video you are talking about?

Comment: yet, i don't know i search it, maybe channel9 when i learn the language and i misunderstood something.

Comment: I know what he is talking about. There are differing tiles which can be done; but my understanding is that there is a deficit in the current preview which doesn't give us the ability to fully do tiles. I don't want to put that as an answer because I cannot verify it at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Small tile is mandatory for your app, the wide tile is optional. If you add a wideTile via the application manifest file than the widetile will be the default.

I also don't think that in later builds of windows 8 this behavior will change. Users should have the option to decide by theirselves if they want a large or a small tile.